# Wicket: form issue - modelObject does not get updated

Tags: forms, model, wicket

I have a page with 2 textfields (with validation as mandatory textfields). Both the text fields have their own save button for some reason. 
Steps to reproduce my error : 
1. Delete all the pre-populated data of textfield #1. Click Save #1. 
[ Validation fails. Error message is received. As expected.] 
2. Use Cancel button and reder to the previous page. 
3. Use Edit button and again render to the original page with 2 textfields. 
4. Delete the data from textfield #2. 
5. Hit save #2. 
6. Save is successful  whereas expected is like before validation should fail.

```
public class FEConfigPanel extends Panel {

public FEConfigPanel(String id, IModel model, FEConfigPage page) {
    super(id, model);
    this.page = page;
    setOutputMarkupId(true);

    add(new Label("chc", "FE Channel Configuration"));
    table = createTable(new FEConfigDataProvider());
    add(table);


    add(new Label("coc", "CC Properties"));
    createCoCForm();
    add(form);
}

private void createCoCForm() {
    form = new Form("form");
    form.add(new LabeledInputPanel("textfield2", "TF2", "TF2AsString",      getConfigModel()));
    form.add(createSaveButton());
}

Component createSaveButton() {
    SubmitLink link = new SubmitLink("save-link", form) {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 304478671323141864L;

        @Override
        public void onSubmit() {
               page.getModelObject();
               ........
        }
    };
    return link;
}

private DataView createTable(FEDataProvider provider) {
    DataView view = new DataView("table", provider, 10) {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = -5704194525968729363L;

        @Override
        protected void populateItem(Item item) {
            FEConfigEntry entry = (FEConfigEntry) item.getModelObject();
            item.add(new Label("textfield1", entry.getTetfield1()));
            ......
        }

    };

    view.setOutputMarkupId(true);
    return view;
}
```

I tried debugging. It seems that the modelobject contains the same old data before my textfield #2 data deletion.

Why ?

Comment: Are you sure textfield2 is required? Just from createCoCForm it doesn't look like it is...

Comment: yes. it is required. for the first time I get proper validation message but the next time I render on this page , I do not get that message. I have debugged and the old default value is set into the textfield2 though I make modifications and click save. I expect my modified value should be set into the textfield2.

Comment: Is the LabeledInputPanel a component from you? Can you post it? And, what does getConfigModel() do?